# How to get author(user)’s multiple language profile through the WordPress REST API

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Polylang of WordPress.
When I try to get author's profile from REST API, I can't find out anything about profile.

Here's sample URI.
http://somewebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users?_embed

Even though I saved my profile in Japnese and English, I could not obtain these author's profile out of API.

Any idea? Do I need to modify WordPress function.php?